# Cutting tilted lines canvas/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've watched a bunch of tutorials and am currently trying to cut the top right piece out, but can only cut in a straight line. Not I'm stuck wondering how I would go by to cut remaining tilted line on this piece. How would I go by doing that?

This is the line I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yliFm.jpg

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8b1a64pm/2/

```
<body>
<canvas id="NewCanvas" height="800" width="800">
</canvas>

</body>
```

And the javascript

```
var can=document.getElementById("NewCanvas");
    var Jctx=can.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
    Jctx.drawImage(img,150,10);
    //drawImage(image,sx,sy,sw,sh,dx,dy,dw,dh);

    Jctx.drawImage(img,150, 45, 150, 100, 100, 300, 150, 100);
    }
    img.src='http://images.sodahead.com/polls/004087283/3238285773_0912_holiday_pie_slicespreview_answer_103_xlarge.jpeg';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the clip method on the new canvas to cut out only part of the original.

Eg

```
// ctx is the new canvas
ctx.save(); // save the current state
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(150,0);
ctx.lineTo(75,150);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // new image is clipped
ctx.restore(); // revert to old state and removes the clip.
```

Comment: This seems like a really good answer, but I'm quite new to this and I'm not sure how to add this to my code. Is there any way you could put this in the fiddle? That would really help me out a lot.

Comment: Just put it in your `img.onload` function replacing your `Jctx.drawImage` calls and replace `ctx` with `Jctx`. You will have to workout the coordinates

Comment: I'm sorry if this is bothering you, but I really cant grasp what I'm supposed to do. I tried changing my `Jctx.drawImage` with `img.onload = function`. This made both my pictures disappear.

Comment: Without the coordinates (what part of the pie you want) I can not help, I don't know what part of the image you need. 'img.onload = function() { /*my answer code here */ }'

Comment: Use an image editor to locate the corners on the pie in pixels. From each coordinate subtract the top left most coordinate. Use that list of coordinates to trace out the clip path `moveTo(x,y)` first point, `lineTo(x,y)` the other points. Then draw the image using the negative top left (because you need to move the pie bit into the new image)  coordinates (before the subtraction)  `Jctx.drawImage(img,-left,-top)`

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much. Sorry for being a hassle, but this really helped me out.

Comment: Good stuff. I don't like just giving an instant solutions, you don't learn much copying some code. Now you should be able to apply it to similar problems. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I just figured out how to do it!! Thank you so much for not giving me an instant solution, because now I really understand. Very much appreciated! @Blindman67